# Unable to Select an Item at the bottom of Long Hover Menu with not visible or out of screen

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit-3.0

If a webpage is with very long HOVER dropdown menu, with using Selenium-Webdriver I can select any element from this menu, but if the element is at the bottom of the menu and outside of the visible screen then Selenium is unable to find that element: e.g.

```
new Actions(driver2).MoveToElement(driver2.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='54Number']"))).Click().Build().Perform();
```

The above element is in the 54th position in the hover menu so it is not being selected by the Selenium. Is there a way to find such a hover element?

Comment: Have you tried just clicking it (not using `Actions`) instead of hovering and then clicking?

Comment: Maybe you can run in headless mode and set window size.

Comment: @JeffC You may not click unless you first move the mouse to a button to see the hover menu appears then scroll the hover menu till the bottom to click the element in the last of the hover menu, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can scroll to an element before clicking:

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='54Number']"));
((IJavaScriptExecutor) driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
element.Click();
```

Comment: Thanks, Evgeniy! however this scroll code is not working for me with HOVER menu as hover menu appears only when you move the mouse to a specific area then you will have to scroll down by using the mouse wheel to see the required element at the bottom of the hover menu